# jQuery UI dialog automatically closing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My parent page invokes a jQuery UI dialog.

In the dialog, I have some form elements and a button with title 'Accept'.

The data, for now, is posted to a spring controller that handles the post and at present does nothing with the data while I am trying to gather some insight of the behavior.

This is my page that is called in the jQuery UI dialog:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    //some stuff
    <button onclick="captureData()">Accept</button>
</form>

function captureData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/captureData.json',
        data: {unmae:UserNmae},
        type: 'post',
        success: function() {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

The data is posted to the spring controller, however what I notice is that after the `alert("success");` the dialog closes on its own.

I'm trying to locate as to what and why the dialog closes on its own.

Comment: I guess its because your form is submitted and so the page reloads.

Comment: Try `<button type="button" onclick="captureData()">`

Comment: or "return false" after the alert.

Comment: `return false` did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion from @ cherhan was the solutions. Use of `return false`